# ORA-01722: invalid number with to_char timestamp

Tags: oracle

First, the table I'm trying to insert into is this table:

```
 CREATE TABLE Message
(
   MessageID varchar2(80) NOT NULL,
   Message varchar2(500),
   SendDate date NOT NULL,     
   SendID varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
   Request_ID varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (MessageID)
);
```

and my insert query is this(Spring, mybatis):

```
 INSERT INTO message (
      messageid
    , message
    , senddate
    , sendId
    , request_Id
)VALUES(
      #{sendidjbuser} + TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24missff3')
    , #{message}
    , sysdate
    , #{sendidjbuser}
    , #{requestIdjbuser}
)
```

I tried this on cmd and this part of the above query was the problem:

```
INSERT INTO message (messageId) VALUES('sendId' + TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'yyyymmddmissff3'))
```

I'm on Oracle 11. I just tried inserting only TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'yyyymmddmissff3') without adding that to a string and it worked. But I do need that part to work. Is there a right way to do that?

Comment: You concat wrong, use `||`

Comment: [Concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators003.htm) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, please use || or CONCAT() function to concatenate strings. You are using '+', hence getting the error.